# ERROR 8152 SQL SERVER String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server

AQUI CON UNA NUEVA DUDA QUE ME HA SURGIDO DURANTE EL DESARROLLO DIARIO. TENGO UN STORE PROCEDURE CUYO RESULTADO EJECUTA UN QUERY STRING, EL RESULTADO ES ORDENADO MEDIANTE ORDER BY OFFSET. CUANDO EJECUTO MI STORE CON PARAMETROS DESDE SSMS ME MANDA EL **ERROR** **8152**: **LOS DATOS DE CADENA O BINARIOS SE TRUNCARIAN**. HE LEIDO MUCHO Y LA MAYORIA DE LAS VECES DICEN QUE E SPOR QUE ESTOY TRATANDO DE GUARDAR MAS DATOS DE LOS PERMITIDOS PERO NO CREO QUE ESE SEA MI ERROR, LES DEJO LA CONSULTA, ESPERO PUEDEN AYUDARME

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[st_SelReporteTipoEquipoLineaTiempo]

@ListContrato VARCHAR(MAX) =NULL,
@ListOTId VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@FechaI DATETIME = NULL,
@FechaF DATETIME = NULL,
@ListTipoEquipo VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@ListPartidas VARCHAR(MAX)='',
@CantInicial INT = -1,
@CantFinal INT = -1,
@GetAll BIT = 0,
--Parametros de paginación--
@PageNumber INT = 1,
@RowsRetrieve INT = 50,
--Parametros de ordenamiento--
@SortColumn VARCHAR(MAX) = 'NoMaterial',
@SortOrder VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DESC'


SET NOCOUNT ON;
Parameter Sniffing 
DECLARE @ListPartidas_ VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ListPartidas_ = @ListPartidas

DECLARE @GetAll_ BIT
SET @GetAll_ = @GetAll

DECLARE @PageNumber_ INT
SET @PageNumber_ = @PageNumber

DECLARE @RowsRetrieve_ INT
SET @RowsRetrieve_ = @RowsRetrieve

DECLARE @SortColumn_ VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SortColumn_ = @SortColumn

DECLARE @SortOrder_ VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SortOrder_ = @SortOrder

IF @GetAll_ = 1 BEGIN
    SET @PageNumber_ = 1
    SET @RowsRetrieve_ = 999999
END

DECLARE @InitialRow INT
SET @InitialRow = ((@PageNumber_ - 1) * @RowsRetrieve_)

DECLARE @lFirstRec INT,
        @lLastRec INT,
        @lTotalRows INT

SET @lFirstRec = ( @InitialRow)
SET @lLastRec = ( @InitialRow + @RowsRetrieve_ + 1 )
SET @lTotalRows = @lFirstRec - @lLastRec + 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsSum AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),

        @sql_Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @docDates NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Remover
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempDates') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tempDates
    END
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EspecificacionObraDia') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #EspecificacionObraDia
    END
--Rango de Fechas[Columnas]
;WITH cte 
AS (SELECT [datelist] = @FechaI 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [datelist] + 1 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE [datelist] + 1 <= @FechaF)
SELECT c.datelist
INTO #tempDates
FROM cte c 
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

DECLARE @TemEquipos TABLE( IdEquipo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                             FechaI DATETIME,
                             FechaF DATETIME,
                             IdAsignacionI UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
                             IsTransferencia  BIT,
                             Propio BIT) 

INSERT INTO @TemEquipos(IdEquipo,FechaI,FechaF,IdAsignacionI,IsTransferencia,Propio) 
EXEC dbo.st_SelHistoricoRentaLineaTiempoTest @FechaI, @FechaF,@ListOTId, NULL, @ListTipoEquipo, @ListContrato; 

--ITERACION DE Equipos
;WITH CTE_FechasEq AS
(
    SELECT 
     epd.IdEquipo,
     epd.IdAsignacionI,
     epd.FechaI,
     epd.FechaF,
     epd.Propio
     FROM @TemEquipos epd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     IdEquipo,
     IdAsignacionI,
     FechaI + 1 AS FechaI,
     FechaF,
     Propio
     FROM CTE_FechasEq
     WHERE --([FechaI] + 1 >= @FechaI ) AND 
     (([FechaI] + 1 <= @FechaF) AND ([FechaI] + 1<=FechaF))
)
    SELECT 
        c.IdAsignacionI,
        c.IdEquipo,
        c.FechaI,
        FechaF,
        dbo.Fn_GetEstimacionCostoLastByEquipo(c.IdEquipo, @FechaF) AS CostoDiario,
        dbo.Fn_GetEstimacionImporteByEquipo(c.IdEquipo,c.FechaI,c.FechaI,0,'573C0A20-2FC0-4E57-B9F7-C482C72DEDB5',0) AS Importe,
        --CASE WHEN c.Propio = 1 THEN 0 ELSE dbo.Fn_GetEstimacionImporteByEquipo(c.IdEquipo,c.FechaI,c.FechaI,0,'573C0A20-2FC0-4E57-B9F7-C482C72DEDB5',0) END AS Importe, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdAsignacionI  ORDER BY IdAsignacionI) AS Orden 
    INTO #EspecificacionObraDia
    FROM CTE_FechasEq c 
    WHERE c.FechaI >= @FechaI
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

    SELECT @docDates = STUFF((SELECT 
                                DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [datelist], 120))
                                FROM [#tempDates]
                                WHERE [datelist] BETWEEN @FechaI AND @FechaF
                                ORDER BY ', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [datelist], 120))
                                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')           
    SET @sql_Query = '
            ; WITH CTE_Reporte AS (
                SELECT * FROM (
                    SELECT
                        p.OT,
                        p.EPEP,
                        p.NumeroPartida,
                        p.Descripcion,
                        p.IdTipoEquipo, --No se registra como columna
                        p.Material,
                        p.NoMaterialSAP,
                        CASE WHEN p.Propio = 1 THEN ''Propios'' ELSE ''Rentados'' END AS Pertenencia,
                        p.FechaI, --No se registra como columna
                        CASE WHEN p.Propio = 1 THEN (SUM(p.Propio) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Material,p.OT,p.NumeroPartida,p.Propio)) ELSE (SUM(p.Rentado) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Material,p.OT,p.NumeroPartida)) END AS TotalEquipos, --No se registra como columna
                        p.CostoDiario AS CostoUnitario,
                        CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,0),((SUM(p.Importe) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Material,p.OT,p.NumeroPartida,p.CostoDiario,p.Propio)) / p.CostoDiario)) AS TotalJornadas,
                        CASE WHEN p.Propio = 1 THEN (SUM(p.Importe) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Material,p.OT,p.NumeroPartida,p.CostoDiario,p.Propio)) ELSE (SUM(p.Importe) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Material,p.OT,p.NumeroPartida,p.CostoDiario,p.Propio)) END AS TotalImporte
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ob.OT,
                            ob.EPEP,
                            par.NumeroPartida,
                            par.Descripcion,
                            te.IdTipoEquipo,
                            te.Material,
                            te.NoMaterialSAP,
                            rep.[Orden],
                            rep.[FechaI],
                            rep.[Importe],
                            rep.[CostoDiario],
                            CASE WHEN rep.Orden = 1 AND eq.Propio = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Propio,
                            CASE WHEN rep.Orden = 1 AND eq.Propio = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Rentado
                        FROM [dbo].[#EspecificacionObraDia] rep
                            INNER JOIN AsignacionEquipo ae ON ae.IdAsignacion=rep.IdAsignacionI
                            INNER JOIN Equipos eq ON eq.IdEquipo = ae.IdEquipo
                            INNER JOIN TipoEquipo te ON te.IdTipoEquipo= eq.IdTipoEquipo
                            INNER JOIN SolicitudLinea sl ON sl.IdSolicitudLinea = ae.IdSolicitudLinea
                            LEFT JOIN PartidaAnexo par ON par.IdPartida = sl.IdPartida
                            INNER JOIN SolicitudEquipo se ON se.IdSolicitud = sl.IdSolicitud
                            INNER JOIN Obra ob ON ob.IdObra = se.IdObra
                        WHERE (ISNULL(''' + @ListPartidas_ + ''','''') = '''' OR par.NumeroPartida IN (SELECT item FROM dbo.fnSplit(''' + @ListPartidas_ + ''' ,'','' )))
                    ) p 
                ) AS [especificacion]

                PIVOT(COUNT([IdTipoEquipo]) FOR [FechaI] IN (' + @docDates + ')) AS [Pivot]
            )

            SELECT
                COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTALCOUNT,
                cteRpt.*
            FROM CTE_Reporte cteRpt
            WHERE
            (ISNULL(''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @CantInicial) + ''',-1) = -1 OR ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @CantInicial) + ''' <= cteRpt.TotalEquipos)
            AND (ISNULL(''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @CantFinal) + ''',-1) = -1 OR ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @CantFinal) + ''' >= cteRpt.TotalEquipos) 
            ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''OT'' THEN cteRpt.OT END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''OT'' THEN cteRpt.OT END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''EPEP'' THEN cteRpt.EPEP END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''EPEP'' THEN cteRpt.EPEP END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''NumeroPartida'' THEN cteRpt.NumeroPartida END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''NumeroPartida'' THEN cteRpt.NumeroPartida END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''Descripcion'' THEN cteRpt.Descripcion END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''Descripcion'' THEN cteRpt.Descripcion END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''Material'' THEN cteRpt.Material END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''Material'' THEN cteRpt.Material END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''NoMaterialSAP'' THEN cteRpt.NoMaterialSAP END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''NoMaterialSAP'' THEN cteRpt.NoMaterialSAP END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''Pertenencia'' THEN cteRpt.Pertenencia END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''Pertenencia'' THEN cteRpt.Pertenencia END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''TotalEquipos'' THEN cteRpt.TotalEquipos END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''TotalEquipos'' THEN cteRpt.TotalEquipos END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''CostoUnitario'' THEN cteRpt.CostoUnitario END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''CostoUnitario'' THEN cteRpt.CostoUnitario END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''TotalJornadas'' THEN cteRpt.TotalJornadas END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''TotalJornadas'' THEN cteRpt.TotalJornadas END ASC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''DESC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''TotalImporte'' THEN cteRpt.TotalImporte END DESC,
                CASE WHEN '''+ @SortOrder + ''' = ''ASC'' AND ''' + @SortColumn + ''' = ''TotalImporte'' THEN cteRpt.TotalImporte END ASC

            OFFSET  ''' + CONVERT(INT,@PageNumber_) + ''' ROWS 
            FETCH NEXT  ''' + CONVERT(INT,@RowsRetrieve_) + ''' ROWS ONLY
            '

            print @sql_Query
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql_Query
            --PRINT @docDates
            --exec (@sql_Query)
END
```

Comment: SEGUN SSMS EL ERROR OCURRE EN LA LINEA145 SELECT @docDates = "DEMÁS CÓDIGO"

Comment: Escribir en mayusculas se considera gritar (ademas queda feo). Si necesitas agregar mas información, podes usar el boton [edit]. No sabemos que devuelve tu query que va a parar a docDates. si te dice que son demasiados datos, seran demasiados datos. Fijate en una tabla, que devuelve ese query.

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]

Comment: Además de todos los problemas que tiene el código que publicas, ahí no se encuentra el error según la línea que mencionas, ya que la ejecución no va a detectar esa linea. Lo más probable es que el error se encuentre en st_SelHistoricoRentaLineaTiempoTest.